# compare rows value in same datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, compare, rows

I want to compare NUMBER rows value with each other

if my grid has a this value

Number
90
90

or

Number
90
80

this code is working .

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)           
{
    for (int ii = i + 1; ii < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ii++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[ii].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Same Number");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Uniq Number");
        }
    }
}
```

if my grid has a this value

Number
90
90

70
70

60
60

above code in looped and not working .

Comment: This is definitely going to throw exceptions...

Comment: I hate looking at poorly named int variables `i and ii` clean up that code

Comment: are you trying to find duplicates over all the records? or are you trying to see if there are the same number twice in a row?